# Is there any setfill() alternative for C?

Tags: c++, c, output-formatting

In C++:

```
int main()
{
    cout << setfill('#') << setw(10) << 5 << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Outputs:

```
#########5
```

Is there any `setfill()` alternative for C? Or how to do this in C without manually creating the string?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there is no direct alternative.

But if you have a well-behaved `snprintf` (one that behaves as described by the C99 Standard), this works without creating a new string; creating only 2 temporary `int`s

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
  int filler = '#'; /* setfill('#') */
  int width = 10;   /* setw(10)     */
  int target = 5;   /* 5            */

  /* ******** */
  int s = snprintf(NULL, 0, "%d", target);
  for (int i = 0; i < width - s; i++) {
    putchar(filler);
  }
  printf("%d\n", target);
  /* ******** */

  return 0;
}
```

---

EDIT: running version at [ideone](http://ideone.com/SUVbZ).

---

EDIT2: Differences between the C99 Standard's `snprintf` and Windows `_snprintf` (*thank you for the link, Ben*):

- prototype: `int snprintf(char *restrict buffer, size_t n, const char *restrict format, ...);`
- prototype: `int _snprintf(char *buffer, size_t n, const char *format, ...);`
- `snprintf` writes no more than (n-1) bytes and a NUL
- `_snprintf` writes no more than (n) bytes, the last of which may be NUL or other character
- `snprintf` returns the number of characters needed for format (can be larger than `n`) or `-1` in case of encoding error
- `_snprintf` returns a negative value if `n` is not large for the string; or `n` if a NUL byte hasn't been written to buffer.

You can run the mis-behaving `_snprintf` in a loop, increasing `n` until you find the right value

```
/* absolutely not tested, written directly on SO text editor */
int i;
size_t rightvalue = 0;
char buffer[SOME_DEFAULT_VALUE];
do {
    if (sizeof buffer < rightvalue) /* OOPS, BIG BIG OOPS */;
    i = _snprintf(buffer, rightvalue, "%d", 42);
} while (i != rightvalue++);
/* rightvalue already has space for the terminating NUL */
```

Comment: `snprintf()` not found in VS2008. what is wrong with `snprintf`?

Comment: VS2008 is not a C99 compiler. Microsoft say so themselves. snprintf first appearance on the Standard was for C99, but it existed "in the wild" before that. Some of those "wild" versions do not work the same way described by the Standard. (I had the idea Windows had one of the mis-behaving "wild" versions)

Comment: It does: `_snprintf`, description here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2ts7cx93.aspx

Answer (score 5):

```
 int x= 5; 
 printf("%010d",x);
```

will output :
     0000000005

Now if you really want '#' instead of '0' you'll have to replace them manually in the string.

Maybe :

```
char buf[11], *sp = buf; 
snprintf(buf, 11, "%10d", x); 
while( (sp = strchr(sp, ' ')) != '\0'){ *sp = '#'; }
puts(buf);
```

Comment: The proper way to use `printf` to print a string variable is `printf("%s", buf);`  Or better yet, use puts.

Answer (score 2):

Everybody wants to call `printf` twice... `printf` is one of the most expensive functions around.

Here:

```
char buffer[18] = "##########";
puts(buffer + snprintf(buffer+strlen(buffer), 8, "%d", 5));
```

Answer (score 1):

Not built in as standard

I would probably sprintf() the number to a string and get the count of characters then output the correct number of '#' first before printing the string.

Answer (score 0):

The following will do it using `memset` in C assuming a 1-byte char.  It still creates a 'string', though I'm not sure how manually you don't want it to be.

```
int main(void)
{

   char buf[MAX_LENGTH];

   memset(buf, '#', 10);
   buf[10]='\0';
   printf("%s5\n", buf);
}
```

Depending what you want to actually do with it, you could dynamically create the buffer to be the appropriate size and return it from a helper function if you so desire.

Comment: No need to assume `sizeof (char) == 1`. The standard defines it as such. (What may change is number of bits, see CHAR_BIT.)

Comment: Assuming the 5 was a variable and not a literal 5 - that would output  10 '#' and then the number - the OP wants to print a field 10chars wide, left filled with #

Comment: Ah indeed, I didn't look closely enough.  Then yeah, you're basically stuck determining the size of whatever you actually want, then combining it with something like the above to pad.